# How to use Vue.js variable in style attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to find a way to use a VueJS variable in a style attribute, as example when I try something like `<p style="color:[% randomColor() %];></p>` it dissapears on my console.

Here's an example on fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/bjfvdgde/3/

**HTML :**

```
<div id="app">
    <p style="color:[% randomColor() %];">[% nameAttr() %]</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var color = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    methods:{
        nameAttr:function(){
          var name = 'John Doe';
          return name 
        },
        randomColor:function(){
            var font_color = "red";
            return font_color
        }
  },
  delimiters: ["[%","%]"]
});
```

How can I get around this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="app">
  <p :style="{color:randomColor()}">[% nameAttr() %]</p>
</div>
```

Read more here: [vue website](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should use **v-bind:style** directive

```
<p v-bind:style="{color:randomColor()}">[% nameAttr() %]</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following snippet for setting the background of a div according to the current image.

```
:style="{'background-image':`url(${currentImg})`}
```

**currentImg** can be replaced by any variable name like **myVariable**